# How to trigger function in arduino by using node-red?

Tags: arduino, node-red

can i trigger a function in arduino with node-red?
i tried to research it before and i couldn't find any
my arduino code is

```
int motor1 = 2;
int motor2 = 3;
int motor3 = 4;
int motor4 = 5;
int motor5 = 6;
int motor6 = 7;
int motor7 = 8;
int motor8 = 9;

void setup() {
pinMode(motor1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor5, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor6, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor7, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor8, OUTPUT);

 }

void loop() {
yeetmotor1();
yeetmotor2();
yeetmotor3();
yeetmotor4();

 }
void yeetmotor1(){  
 digitalWrite(motor1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motor2, LOW);
 delay(1000);
 digitalWrite(motor1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motor2, LOW);
 }
void yeetmotor2(){  
digitalWrite(motor3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(motor4, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(motor3, LOW);
digitalWrite(motor4, LOW);
 }
void yeetmotor3(){  
digitalWrite(motor5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(motor6, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(motor5, LOW);
digitalWrite(motor6, LOW);
 }
void yeetmotor4(){  
digitalWrite(motor7, HIGH);
digitalWrite(motor8, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(motor7, LOW);
digitalWrite(motor8, LOW);
}
```

If you have any clue for this please send help because i think it is possible to do it
Thank you for anying answering it

Comment: You've not actually said what you want this code to do. As it stands it will always just run everything in the `loop()` function, there is nothing you could trigger it to do different. Edit the question to give more detail about what outcome you actually want.

Comment: Also you've not said how the arduino is attached to what ever is running Node-RED

Comment: Short answer is Yes if you have a way to communicate between your Arduino and the Web Server where the Node-RED is running, either directly or wirelessly.

Comment: For a starter, I have a tutorial on how to control [Raspberry Pi GPIO using node-RED](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/02/control-raspberry-pi-gpio-using-node-red/), but in your case, you will need to replace the code for reading GPIO from Raspberry Pi to get data from Arduino, and easiest way is to via UART between Arduino and the web server. Good luck.